# What does "rep cap was exceeded on 4 days" mean?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

When I open https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, I see at the bottom of the page that,

> days represented 34 rep cap was
>   reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 
>   4 days
>   rep cap was exceeded on 4 days

What does it mean? Few days back, it said "rep cap was exceeded on 3 days". What is this "4 days" and "3 days"?

Also, what is the maximum reputation one can get each day? What does "cap" mean?

Comment: It is a count of how often  you reached the 200 limit. There are 2 slightly overlapping definitions. And there are two badges involved, that's why some people want to know.

Comment: You may find the answers you seek at this -- admittedly confusing -- post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to clarify, from how I understand it:

- Rep cap reached means you got at least 20 upvotes during that day (community wikis not included). Or in another way: If you got 200 points counting only upvotes.
- Rep cap exceeded means you got at least 201 points during that day.

So, if you get 20 or more upvotes, but no accepted answers, you'll get 200 points (less if you also got downvotes or voted down). That means your "reached" count increases, but not your "exceeded" count.

If you have *less* than 20 upvotes, but *more* than 200 points (for example 19 upvotes, and one accepted answer = 205 points) your "exceeded" count will increase, but your "reached" count will not.

If you get 20 or more upvotes plus at least one accepted answer, both the "reached" and "exceeded" count will increase.

Answer (score -1):

From the faq:

> you can earn a maximum of 200
>   reputation per day (although accepted
>   answers and bounty awards are immune
>   to this limit). Also, please note that
>   votes for any posts marked "community
>   wiki" do not generate reputation.

Comment: jzd : and what is that "4 days" and "3 days" mean?

Comment: The number of days that you hit your limit of 200 reputation per day.

Comment: @Downvoter : could you please explain what's wrong with this answer so that I can understand?

Comment: Well, wasn't me, but it doesn't really answer the question, does it?